AMS in IBM MQ - Spring Boot Application - 'org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject.getObject()'
We are trying to connect an IBM MQ from spring boot application for which AMS is enabled. But we see that the message is consumed and at spring boot application level, during unprotect an exception is thrown. The Bouncy castle jar is compatible, and the same application worked few days back. Below is the stack trace of the error. Any insights how this exception can be sorted? Thanks for your time in advance
WARN  org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'IBM.MQ' -
trying to recover. Cause: 'org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject.getObject()'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject.getObject()'
at org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on.jar:1.68.0]
at org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on.jar:1.68.0]
at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source) ~[bcpkix-jdk15on.jar:1.68.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source) ~[bcpkix-jdk15on.jar:1.68.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[bcpkix-jdk15on.jar:1.68.00.0]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.prot.MessageProtectionBCImpl.unprotect(MessageProtectionBCImpl.java:742) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.prot.MessageProtectionWrapper.unprotect(MessageProtectionWrapper.java:99) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.unprotect(JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.java:2264) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.process(JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.java:1284) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.unprotectMessage(JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.java:661) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 -p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.afterGet(JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.java:512) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.afterJmqiGet(JmqiGetInterceptorImpl.java:222) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiGet(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:1377) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiGet(ESEJMQI.java:602) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1795) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:228) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0- p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1461) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:674) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1051) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:667) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:209) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:9.2.2.0 - p922-L210310.DE]
at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:431) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:316) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) [spring-jms-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]

We tried upgrading the bouncy castle jars to sort this, but this is not sorted. We also need information on where to download all ibm mq compatible dependencies.

seems like a dependency issue, since it worked few days back check which dependencies were changes in that time, and identify the causing issue

actually I reverted back the changes exactly as same as previous and still it did not work out

To help diagnosing, please share the dependencies section of your pom.xml

If you are basing on the IBM MQ JMS Spring Boot Starter then all the requisite libraries will be pulled in. Current latest version is 3.3.3
ie. Add the following to the list of dependencies in your pom.xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>

